# How I can stop a timer with seconds in real time c#?

Tags: c#, timer, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to stop a timer when 16 seconds in real time have passed, but i don't know how i can do that.

I made this little example: when picturebox1 intersects with picturebox2,this action activate a timer, and this timer have to shows the picturebox3 during 16 seconds in real time and after stop it(timer) (and the picturebox3 doesn't show).

(Sorry for my english. But StackOverflow in Spanish doesn't have many information).

I'm using windows form and C#

```
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox7.Hide();
        if ((pictureBox3.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Visible) || (pictureBox5.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Visible))
        {                
            puntaje++;
            this.Text = "Puntaje: " + puntaje;
            if (puntaje % 5 == 0)
            {
               timer3.Enabled=true;
 //This is the part where i want set down the timer3, timer 2 is on

            }
        }
```

Comment: Does your timer need to be very accurate? As in exactly 16.0000000000 seconds? If you don't that level of precision then please see `System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed` event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way I can see this implemented is by using the interval parameter of a `System.Timers.Timer`.

Here's a sample snippet of the code

```
var timer = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16).TotalMilliseconds) { AutoReset = false };
timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Finished at exactly {timer.Interval} milliseconds");
};
_timer.Start();
```

The `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16).TotalMilliseconds` basically converts to 16000 but I used the TimeSpan static method for you to understand it easier and looks more readable.

The AutoReset property of the timer tells it that it should only be triggered once.

Adjusted for your code

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox7.Hide();
    if ((pictureBox3.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Visible) 
        || (pictureBox5.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Visible))
    {                
        puntaje++;
        this.Text = "Puntaje: " + puntaje;
        if (puntaje % 5 == 0)
        {
            var timer3 = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16).TotalMilliseconds) { AutoReset = false };
            timer3.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                pictureBox3.Visible = true;
            };
            timer3.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Please do mark the question Answered if this solves your issue.

Comment: How i can impliment that in this code? I'm very confused...             private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
            pictureBox7.Hide();
            if ((pictureBox3.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Visible) || (pictureBox5.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Visible))
            {
                puntaje++;
                this.Text = "Puntaje: " + puntaje;
                if (puntaje % 5 == 0) {
                    timer3.Enabled=true;
                }
            }

Comment: @DannyJ.Parr add that code in your post so i can edit accordingly

Comment: @DannyJ.Parr adjusted

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, on your timer tick event handler. Timespan counts the elapsed time between two dates. On this case since its 16 seconds, we count it by negative.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = dtStart.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        if (ts.TotalSeconds <= -16)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Make sure your dtStart (DateTime) is declared when you start your timer:

```
timer1.Start();
dtStart = DateTime.Now;
```